# Infinite sum for Hypergeometric ${_{1}F_0}$ function

Tags: sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function

I am attempting to show the following:

$$ {_{1}F_0} \left(\begin{matrix} -x \\ - \end{matrix} \Bigg| \frac{t}{a}\right)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)_k}{k!a^k} t^k = \left(1-\frac{t}{a}\right)^x$$

Where : $$(-x)_k = -x(-x+1)(-x+2)(-x+3)...(-x+k-1)$$
And:
$$ (-x)_0=1$$

I tried just writing out the sum, but I don't see where to go:

$$-x-x(1-x)\frac{t}{a}-\frac{x(1-x)(2-x)}{2!}\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)^2-\frac{x(1-x)(2-x)(3-x)}{3!}\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)^3...$$

$$ -x \left[1+(1-x)\frac{t}{a}+\frac{(1-x)(2-x)}{2!}\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)^2+\frac{(1-x)(2-x)(3-x)}{3!}\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)^3...\right] $$

Any help is appreciated. Tank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your summation expansion is off by $1$ for $\quad(-x)_k = (-x)(-x+1)\cdots(-x+k-1).\quad$ The right side of your equation is expanded as the binomial series. 
$$\left(1-\frac{t}{a}\right)^x =1 + \frac{(-x)}{1!}\frac{t}{a}+ \frac{(-x)(-x+1)}{2!}\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)^2+\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \binom {x}{k}\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)^k,$$
but this is equal to the hypergeometric series in your case.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks!